# Callback not calling on autosave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
  before_save :update_something
private
  def update_something
    self.update_column(:something, "something")
  end
end
```

And

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, autosave: true
end
```

I expect that when I save an instance of `Thing` that it's `Parent` should also be saved. I also expect that instance of `Parent` to have it's `before_save` callback called. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Any idea why this doesn't work and how I might remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the docs

> If you set the :autosave option to true, Rails will save any loaded
>   members and destroy members that are marked for destruction whenever
>   you save the parent object.

I suggest you creating new after_save callback for Thing to update parent if you want to go Rails way.

But the OO way would be to create class that handles saving the object, such as:

```
class ThingUpdater
  def initialize(thing)
    @thing = thing
  end

  def call(params)
    @thing.update_attributes(params)
    @thing.parent.update_something
  end
end
```

Thanks to this you will avoid callback hell - take also a [look here](http://sharkzp.github.io/blog/2013/12/16/callbacks-extraction/)